# Woocommerce sold individually feature based on product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, categories

I have a woocommerce site I use the booster plugin to enable sold individually for each product but now I want to sold individually for each category and if someone add a product to cart on a category then can not add another product of that category to cart

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: I want nobody can add two product from one category to cart

Comment: You can do it via cart hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below there is 2 functions:

- The 1st one is a conditional function checking categories in cart items
- The 2nd one will avoid add to cart when a product category already exist in cart items and will display a custom message.

The code:

```
// Conditional function: Checking product categories in cart items
function check_cats_in_cart( $product_id ) {
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $has_term = true;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $item['product_id'], $taxonomy ) as $term ){
            // Allowing add to cart the same product
            if( has_term( $term->slug, $taxonomy, $product_id ) ){
                $has_term = false;
                break; // stops the 2nd loop
            }
        }
        // Allowing the same product to be added (not activated. you can uncomment lines below)
        # if ( $item['product_id'] == $product_id  )
        #   $has_term = true;

        if( $has_term )
            break; // stops the 1st loop
    }
    return $has_term;
}

// Avoid add to cart when a product category already exist in cart items, displaying a custom error message
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'sold_individually_by_cats_valid', 10, 3 );
function sold_individually_by_cats_valid( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {

    $passed = check_cats_in_cart( $product_id );

    if( ! $passed ){
        // Displaying a custom message
        $message = __("This product category is already in cart. Try another product", "woocommerce");
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> If you want to allow adding to cart again the same product (that increases only the quantity of an existing product), you will uncomment this code in the function:

> ```
>        if ( $item['product_id'] == $product_id  )
> ```

```
            $has_term = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this one

```
function is_product_the_same_cat($valid, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
         return true;
    }
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );
        $target_terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $cat_ids[] = $term->term_id;  
        }
        foreach ($target_terms as $term) {
            $target_cat_ids[] = $term->term_id; 
        }           
    }
    $same_cat = array_intersect($cat_ids, $target_cat_ids);
    if(count($same_cat) > 0) return $valid;
    else {
        wc_add_notice( 'This product is in another category!', 'error' );
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'is_product_the_same_cat',10,3);
```

I found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523092/woocommerce-only-allow-products-from-the-same-category-in-cart)